# Por que o Workflow do GitHub não inicia?

Tags: workflow, github

Criei no meu [repositório](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/PyMemoryEditor) (atualmente, branch master) do GitHub um Workflow para rodar os testes da minha aplicação em Python, utilizando o `pytest`. Configurei ele para rodar em `ubuntu-latest` nas versões do Python (3.6, 3.7 e 3.8) sempre que fosse enviado um *push* ou um *pull request*.

Veja abaixo o meu arquivo `.yml`:

```
name: Python Package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ['3.6', '3.7', '3.8']

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest tests -v -s
    - name: Install package
      run: |
        pip install FlightRadarAPI
```

O problema é que o GitHub não inicializa o Workflow e fica aparecendo na tela a seguinte mensagem, em baixo da logo:

```
This workflow has no runs yet.
```

Adicionei um arquivo `README.md` para atualizar o repositório e ver se o Workflow inicializava, mas continuou do mesmo jeito. O que está acontecendo? O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso que dá ficar copiando e colando. :P

Você está dizendo explicitamente para rodar esse *workflow* somente na *branch* `main`:

> ```
> on:
>   push:
>     branches: [ main ]
>   pull_request:
>     branches: [ main ]
> ```

Esse campo deve, obviamente, ser seguido a risca. Mas o seu repositório (conforme link apontado na pergunta) está na *branch* `master`.

- Ou você muda a *branch* de `master` para `main`.
- Ou você muda a configuração do *workflow*, para rodar na *branch* `master` ao invés de `main`.

Comment: "Isso que dá ficar copiando e colando". Por um momento pensei que você era vidente kkk. Obrigado pela resposta.